# Find smallest product of 3 numbers in the array [error in code?]

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a code to do just that, but I do not complete all test cases on the website I put it on. Since I do not know what the tests are I tried to run some on my own, but I am unable to find the problem.

Now, I understand that my code can be simplified, but I made it bigger for clarity. I am a noob, don't hate.

Examples:

For arr = [1, 2, 3], the output should be smallestProduct(arr) = 6

The only option is 1 * 2 * 3 = 6.

For arr = [-1, 0, -2, 3], the output should be smallestProduct(arr) = 0
There are four possible products, and the smallest one is 0:

EDIT: I solve the challenge with:
EDIT2: Yeah, I missed 0. Damn it.

```
Arays.sort(arr);
 return Math.min(arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2], arr[0] * arr[arr.length-1] * arr[arr.length-2] );
```

But I would like to know what was wrong with ifs and elses

```
public static int smallestProduct(int[] arr) {

        Arrays.sort(arr);
     //all positive
    if (arr[0] > 0) {
        return  arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2];
    }

    //all negative
    else if (arr[arr.length-1] < 0){

        return arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2];
    }

    //one is negative
    else if (arr[0] < 0 && arr[1] > 0) {

        return  arr[0] * arr[arr.length-1] * arr[arr.length-2];
    }

    //two negative
    else if (arr[0] < 0 && arr[1] < 0 && arr[2] > 0) {
        return arr[0] * arr[arr.length-1] * arr[arr.length-2];
    }

    //more than two negative
    else {

        return arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any failing test case that you know of that you test yourself with input and expected + actual output?

Comment: All the `if` branches return the same result: `arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2]`

Comment: @Héctor only if the array has exactly 3 elements

Comment: what about if an element is `0` ?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Oh sorry, you're right. I misunderstood the question

Comment: @Héctor understandable... a [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input array and the expected output? I don't get what you want to achieve...

Comment: can you add an example of arr[] , and an expected result?

Comment: codesignal challenge https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/8FdeLisamv6cFZPAc
you can find many solutions after challenge.
think about negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about performance, you can use this brute-force snippet:

```
private static int smallestProduct(int[] array){
    long smallest = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
            for(int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++){
                final long product = (long) array[i] * array[j] * array[k];
                if(smallest > product){
                    smallest = product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

It works by taking 2 times the cartesian product of the array. And then seeing if that product is smaller than the initial one.

---

As said this is just something i've come up with. Using one of the conditional algorithms from the other answer may work better and more efficient.

Comment: not bad, but you could avoid the check if the indices are equal by just starting every inner loop with the value of the previous index plus 1: `for (int i = 0; ...) { for (int j = i+1; ...` (since `a[i]*a[j] == a[j]*a[i]`)  ((Gruss in die CH))

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger oh yeah I first thought about that too, but I couldn't come up with a solution, so I just took the easy way with the `if`-statements. ((Einen zurück (: ))

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger how does this change the time complexity?